# Can I directly reference a general selector if only one reference is available in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

So say this is the code of my whole page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then I want to update the content of that textarea. I can't add an id to that textarea, it has to stay as-is.

My question is, normally with many textareas, I'd update it like this:

```
$('textarea').each(function () {
  $(this).text('foo');
});
```

But in this case, where there's only one textarea, am I allowed to write this:

```
$('textarea').text('foo');
```

I'm only using `.text` as an example. I just want to see if the two pieces of code mentioned supra have the same effect when there's only one element of a specific type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `text` there is no need to use `each` as it changes text content of all selected elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/GhVGP/

Comment: But what with other selectors? I don't know, `.css`, `.trigger`, etc. Is it all the same?

Comment: @think123 This is the case for some methods, same for `css` for example, it changes style of 1 or more selected elements, but not for `html` method when you wants to get the html content of the elements, it only gets the html content of the first selected element. http://jsfiddle.net/GhVGP/7/ - http://jsfiddle.net/GhVGP/9/

Answer (score 2):

Both pieces of code will result absolutely the same effect no metter how much textareas you have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're equivalent.

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2):

> Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.

So if your collection contains more than one element, the text of every element in that collection will be set to the specified one.

So, using `.each()` to loop over the collection is useless in this case, and it's also slower.

---

Generally speaking, all of jQuery's manipulation methods can operate on all the elements of a collection.

Setters operate on the whole collection:

- [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) *Adds the specified class(es) to each of the set of matched elements.*
- [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2) *Set the CSS height of every matched element.*

Getters operate on the first element of the collection:

- [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height1) *Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements.*

[`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text1) (as getter) is bit different, because in case it's used as getter on a collection, it returns the combined text of the elements in the collection:

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.text` method when refering to multiple elements. The setter `.text(string)` affects all elements in the jQuery object, and the getter `.text` concatenates the text of all elements. There is also a `.text(function(index, text))`, that calls the function over every element it wants to change.
http://api.jquery.com/text/

The same applies to most other methods: The setters affect all elements, and the getters read (usually) the first element.

You can use any function at any time. If the jQuery object contains only one element, no matter if the selector used to obtain the object may refer to multiple elements, the methods that access an element (text, value, css), may be used and they will access the single element selected.

If you want to be extra-sure the selector will only select one element, you can use the :first pseudo-class (`$("textarea:first")`)

By the way, a `textarea` should be accessed with `.value(...)` (which works for `input`s), not `.text(...)` (which doesn't).